# HttpModule: Open a pdf file will raise several PreRequestHandlerExecute event

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I'm writing a small asp.net program used to log information whenever some pdf files is accessed. I use httpmodle to achieve that. But the problem is if the pdf file is big (>1M or so), more than one PreRequestHandlerExecute events will be raised (if I download the file, only one event will be raised). These pdf files belong to another web app. If possible, I don't want to touch that app. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the information you are logging you might be able to save yourself some work just by parsing the server log files using something like [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I ever used log parser to do it, but I found it is not suitable for my case. IIS will not write the information to its log file immediately. 
Here what I don't understand is why asking a pdf from server will trigger PreRequestHandlerExecute several times. And it seems that bigger the file more events was raised.

After checking the log file of IIS I found there are several log records for the same pdf request. So...